# How can I let registered users upload images using a form in Drupal 7?

Tags: media, forms, files

I'm using Gallery formatter on my Drupal 7 site which allows administrators to upload images to my articles that are then shown on the article body. So great so far, but what I want is for the registered users themselves to upload images to the article using a form. I've been searching for a while, but haven't been able to find anything that would allow me to do this.

Is there a module that would allow image upload using a form that integrates with Gallery formatter (or just Drupal Image - both would work, I think, as the images are stored in a field), or do I have to create a custom module?

Answer (score 1):

You need the [field permission module](http://drupal.org/project/field_permissions). Everything is already contained in Drupal core.

1. Create a content type.
2. Add an image field and allow multiple instances of this field.
3. With help of the field permission module make sure registered users have the right to edit your image field.
4. Configure ImageCache to output the images the way you want.

As an add on you might have a look at views, wich allows you to output many nodes with their images, sorted and/or filtered the way you want.